# Adding flags to static lib compilation

Tags: c++, makefile

Good day!lets say I have a makefile that compils a static library.

```
CC = g++





SOURCES  =  $(wildcard way_to_src/src/*.cpp)
INCLUDES = -Iway_to Incl
OBJECTS  = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

CFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)


TARGET_STATIC    =    libmy_.a




clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET_SO) $(TARGET_STATIC) 

static :  $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $(TARGET_STATIC) $(OBJECTS)
```

How can I add '-fpermissive' flag to compilation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `CXXFLAGS`:

```
CXXFLAGS=-fpermissive
```

Also `CFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)` should also target `CXXFLAGS`:

```
CXXFLAGS += -fpermissive $(INCLUDES)
```

Comment: As `-I` is a preprocessor option `CPPFLAGS := $(INCLUDES)` should work for both.